# Do the starting abilities actually do anything?

Tags: candy-box

At the beginning of Candy Box, you can only eat candy or throw candy on the ground. Do either of these actions have any effect on anything else in the game?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eating candies increases your max health, dropping candies on the floor appears to do nothing, although you do get a progressively sadder face next to the count as you dump more.

Answer (score 9):

To extend @Sconibulus's answer:

```
setNbrThrown : function(value){
    this.nbrThrown = value;

    // We choose which smiley we want to add at the end of the sentence
    if(this.nbrThrown <= 10) smiley = ".";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 20) smiley = "...";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 30) smiley = "...?";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 40) smiley = "...? <tt>:|</tt>";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 50) smiley = "...? <tt>:/</tt>";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 60) smiley = "...? <tt>:(</tt>";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 70) smiley = "...? <tt>:[</tt>";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 80) smiley = "...? <tt>:{</tt>";
    else if(this.nbrThrown <= 90) smiley = "...? <tt>:'(</tt>";
    else smiley = "...? <tt>(;_;)</tt>";

    if(this.nbrThrown != 1) htmlInteraction.setInnerHtml("candies_thrown", "You threw " + this.nbrThrown + " candies on the ground" + smiley);
    else htmlInteraction.setInnerHtml("candies_thrown", "You threw 1 candy on the ground" + smiley);
    htmlInteraction.setElementVisibility("candies_thrown", true);
},
```

Throwing candies on the ground does nothing immediately. However, in the computer section (I'm not there yet, I just did a search through all the .js files. This is in `computer.js`):

```
    bug2: function() {
        var rndrnd;
        if (lollipops.nbrOwned >= 10000000) {
            lollipops.setNbrOwned(lollipops.nbrOwned - 10000000);
            switch (random.getRandomIntUpTo(2)) {
                case 0:
                    candies.setNbrOwned(candies.nbrOwned + candies.nbrThrown);
                    htmlInteraction.setInnerHtml("computer_comment_2", "You picked up all candies you have thrown on the floor. (" + candies.nbrThrown + ")");
                    candies.setNbrThrown(0);
                    break;
```

It appears there is a point where you have the option of picking up all the candies you throw on the floor. I don't know why you would want to do this (a way to store candies for later?), but it is apparently an option.

Comment: There should also be a comment at the top of the code that tells you you're cheating. :P on a side note, that picking up all the candies on the floor option is only available after you beat the game at a cost of 100 milion lolipops, and even at that it is random whether you get the option or not. Can't say much detail without spoiling it.

Comment: At the time of getting that you'll already be getting billions of candies, but good answer.

Comment: Note: This game has been updated.  There is now a dark mode that unlocks after throwing >= 100 candies

Answer (score 2):

Per [this interview](http://kotaku.com/candy-box-a-game-thats-simple-sweet-and-strangely-c-492318079), throwing the candies on the ground does nothing.

> Every action you take seems to lead to a new discovery, except one.
>
> "Throwing the candies on the ground does nothing," aniwey said, adding a smile.