# What affects the amount of hitpoints each eaten candy increases?

Tags: candy-box

[Eating candies increase max health](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116113/4797). I'm currently trying to balance my hitpoints on my current playthrough, as I had encountered a [problem finishing a certain quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116155/4797) on a previous playthrough due to eating too much candy.

I tried computing the HP I get from three different saved games, but I get different computations for each:

> Default hitpoints: 100
>
> *Save # 1*
>   Candies eaten: 1179994540874
>   HP: 141670
>
> 1179994540874 candies / (141670 - 100) HP = 8335060.68 candies / HP
>
> *Save # 2*
>   Candies eaten: 300004 candies
>   HP: 425
>
> 300004 candies / (425 - 100) HP = 923.09 candies / HP
>
> *Save# 3*
>   Candies eaten: 370 candies
>   HP: 122
>
> 370 candies / (122 - 100) HP = 16.82 candies / HP

---

Hence, I would like to ask:

- **What affects the amount of hitpoints each candy increases?**
- **By how much will eating one candy raise max health?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a formula that yields diminishing returns per-candy.

## Max HP = 100 + 2.1 * Candies^0.4

(Where 'Candies' = candies eaten, obvs)

Answer (score 4):

Taking the derivative with respect to candies...

Each candy will give you +(.84/(candies eaten^.6)) to your max health.

Comment: This is just the formule from @LessPop_MoreFizz's answer in another form...