# Why throw candy on the ground?

Tags: candy-box-2

What is the point of throwing candy on the ground using the "Throw 10 candies on the ground"? All that seems to happen is that the text under it becomes more and more disappointed in me. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: i have thrown 700 and still nothing

Comment: Eat the Candy and a merchant will appear. From that point the game is self explanatory. Also, Duplicate:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116113/do-the-starting-abilities-actually-do-anything

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta - That's in Candy Box 1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Throw enough candies (1630) on the ground and the guy (._.) will dig a hole (because he gets annoyed by your candy wasting). He falls into a room that contains something.

> a chocolate bar

Around 2000 Candies (1770), he digs into another room. In this room, there are giant candies.
He stays in the room and keeps eating them.

He doesn't do anything else after that, just eating those giant candies.

Comment: How many is 'enough'?

Comment: I can confirm (from looking at the source code) that he doesn't do anything else after that.

Comment: I've thrown 22,000 and still nothing

Comment: I've thrown 150,000, I wish I read this earlier

Answer (score 1):

As you continue to throw candy it starts adding punctuation. Then it adds some smiley sad faces. Then it adds this little guy: (o_o)
He yells at you for throwing candy and says stop stop stop. But if you keep throwing he says whatever and attempted to run away but hits a wall and says whatever and tries digging into the ground and falls through a hole and finds a chest. You get a chocolate bar. Then he tries digging again and finds a large room full of candy. So far at 3,600 candy thrown, that's all i've found. It seems as if that's it.

Basically throw enough candy to get 1 chocolate bar.

Answer (score 0):

the more candy you throw on the ground the better it will get-his face will change he'll say a quote and once you reach enough you will get a chocolate bar!

After that he will dig even more, and he'll find a ton of giant candy (you dont get any) and then from there on out when you throw candy on the ground he will just eat it.

Answer (score -9):

This may not be correct information, throwing candy on the ground does not open the hole, only changes the little symbols at the ed of the sentence

Comment: Wrong. Spoiler: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/spoilercandy.PNG